# How to Add prefix to all file in current folder and subfolder using batch file

Tags: windows, subdirectory, batch-rename

I am trying to add prefix to all files in current folder and it's subfolders and i made the following batch file

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%j in (*) do (
set filename=%%j
rename !filename! [nilesh.uk.to]-!filename!
)
```

it working for current directory only but i want to add prefix to all files in current folder as well as subdirectory please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this from another folder, and the pushd is used otherwise the batch file will be renamed too. Change `c:\mainfolder` to your main folder name

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\mainfolder\"
for /r %%j in (*) do (
   rename "%%j" "[nilesh.uk.to]-%%~nxj"
)
popd
```

Comment: setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in (*) do (
  set "FN=%%F"
  set "FN=!FN:~15!"
  ren "%%F" "!FN!"
)
goto :eof this is the code now i want to conver it for all subfolder and current folder

Answer (score 0):

using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer), you can do it in one command like this:

```
$ renamer --regex --find '^' --replace 'prefix-' '**'
```